# Open mdf file that resides in App_Data with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, ssms, mdf

Is there a one-click way to open an mdf file that resides in the App_Data of the current editing project in Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server Mangement Studio 2008 R2?

UPDATE:

I am also looking for the opposite way, where I want to execute a generated SQL script to a database that resides as an mdf file in the local App_Data folder.

Comment: Yes there is, see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024873/sql-server-wont-open-db-created-by-visual-studio

Comment: Not only it's not a one-clicker, but it doesn't allow the db to work in both VS and SMSS simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not a one click way as SQL Server does not allow mdf to be shared when it is attached to the SQL Engine.

Comment: I've added some content to my question